# How to automatically run consul agent and registrator container on scaling ECS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, consul, hashicorp-otto

I have created a consul cluster of three nodes. Now **I need to run consul agent and registrator containers and join consul agent with one of the consul server node whenever I up ECS instance or scale out ECS instance on which I'm running my micro services.**

I have automated rest of the deployment process with rolling updates. *But I have to manually start up consul agent and registrator whenever I scale out ECS instance.*

Anyone have idea how can we automate this?

Comment: @Takarii: Currently I have to run consul agent and registrator manually on ECS insatnce whenever I scale it out. I want to automate this task. I run these commands:                                                                             export PRIVATE_IP=[your private IP here];    export JOIN_IP=[IP of consul server node];
$(docker run --rm progrium/consul cmd:run $PRIVATE_IP::10.0.0.113::client -d -it);
   
docker run -d --name registrator \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock \
    -h $HOSTNAME gliderlabs/registrator consul://$PRIVATE_IP:8500

Comment: Try this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/start_task_at_launch.html and https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-an-amazon-ecs-task-on-every-instance/

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a task-definition with two containers, consul-client and registrator.
2. `aws ecs start-task` in your userdata.

[This AWS post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-an-amazon-ecs-task-on-every-instance/) focuses on this.

**edit**: Since you mentioned ECS instance, I assume you already have the necessary IAM role set for the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Create an ELB in front of you consul servers or an elastic IP so that it doesn't change.

Then in userdata:

```
#!/bin/bash
consul_host=consul.mydomain.local

#start the agent
docker run -it --restart=always -p 8301:8301 -p 8301:8301/udp -p 8400:8400 -p 8500:8500 -p 53:53/udp \
-v /opt/consul:/data -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /etc/consul:/etc/consul -h \
$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) --name consul-agent progrium/consul \
-join $consul_host -advertise $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)`

#start the registrator
docker run -it --restart=always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock \
-h $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) --name consul-registrator \
gliderlabs/registrator:latest -ip $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4) \
consul://$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4):8500
```

Note: this snippet assumes your setup is all locally reachable, etc. It's from the cloudformations from [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/service-discovery-via-consul-with-amazon-ecs/) and [this link](https://github.com/awslabs/service-discovery-ecs-consul)